# How get and use list of fields' name in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I store price changes data for each date in MongoDB as following:

```
{ "_id" : "A1",
  "Price" : 
     {
         "2020-08-25": {"P" : [1200, 1300, 1250]},
         "2020-08-26": {"P" : [1310, 1400, 1200]},
         "2020-08-27": {"P" : [1500, 1300, 1300]},
         ...
     }
 
 },
 { "_id" : "A2",
   "Price" :
     {
          "2020-08-25": {"P" : [1200, 1300, 1250]},
         "2020-08-26": {"P" : [1310, 1400, 1200]},
         "2020-08-27": {"P" : [1500, 1300, 1300]},
         ...
     }
 }
```

Now, I want to get maximum price **for all dates**. How I can do it without writing each date field in my query? I mean, for a specific date like as "2020-08-25", someone can uses $group and $max to obtain maximum price value in that date. But, how write a query to get maximum price value among all dates?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the maximum price for all dates in the collection you need to run an aggregate operation that first gets the maximum for each document and this can be achieved using the [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) and [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operators to create an array of price values which can be easily extrapolated for a maximum value.

To get the array values you first need to convert the `Price` document to an array of key/value pairs of dates and the prices using [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/)

```
db.getCollection('collection').aggregate([
    { '$set': {
       'maxPricePerDocument':  {
           '$max': {
               '$map': {
                   'input': { '$objectToArray': '$Price' },
                   'in': { '$max': '$$this.v.P' }
               }
           }
       }
    } },
    { '$group': {
        '_id': 0,
        'maxPriceForEntireCollection': { '$max': '$maxPricePerDocument' }
    } }
])
```

Comment: Thank you so much @chridam for this solution. I just wondering about the performance of $objectToArray. I have millions of records of data. Dose $objectToArray is fast enough? Or the better way is that to change my data storing approach? For example, a solution is to store each price as [{"date": "2020-08-25", "p":1200}, {"date": "2020-08-25", "p":1300}, {"date": "2020-08-25", "p":1250}, {"date": "2020-08-26", "p":1310}, {"date": "2020-08-26", "p":1400}, ...]. In this way, the size of data increase, but I am not sure the performance of different queries is better or worse?

Comment: @AsefPourmasoomi Haven't actually benchmarked the performance of the particular operator but one thing I'm sure of is it's much better to store the data in the latter way i.e. `[{"date": "2020-08-25", "p":1200}, {"date": "2020-08-25", "p":1300}, {"date": "2020-08-25", "p":1250}, {"date": "2020-08-26", "p":1310}, {"date": "2020-08-26", "p":1400}, ...]` since that way you can just do `{ maxPrice: { $max: { '$Price.p' } } }` without the need of converting the document first to an array so in a way that can considerably perform better.

Comment: Tnx, For this query the performance might be better. But, suppose u want to query on a specific date. For example, u want to do some processes on prices of "2020-08-26". The first way probably might be better. Because u can access to data directly using price["2020-08-26"]. On the other hand, I am not sure that it is possible to define index on a key of an array (in second approach, date field). So, In second approach to access to data of a specific date we should add a where condition using $match on a unindexed field. So, probably, the first approach might be better for this query.

Comment: @AsefPourmasoomi of course you can index an array. They call it [multi-key index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/) There are other concerns like an array can have items with the same date etc but it's out of scope. I am curious whether Chris' $map-$max is any better than Gibbs' $group-$max. It would be great to learn if you can compare performance of both queries.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex. I think I should test both of them and I will share the result. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

To get across the collection

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      "prices": {
        "$objectToArray": "$Price"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": null,
      P: {
        $addToSet: {
          $max: "$prices.v.P"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "maxPrice": {
        $max: {
          $first: "$P"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/j5fPbW_1Axx)

---

Date specific:
[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZHQNyP_iTzi)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      "prices": {//reshape it to perform object wise operations - mainly converting to array
        "$objectToArray": "$Price"
      }
    }
  },
  {//getting one by one entries
    "$unwind": "$prices"
  },
  {
    $group: {//grouping by date and getting the max from local entry
      "_id": "$prices.k",
      "values": {
        $max: "$prices.v.P"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "date": "$_id",
      "maxPrice": {//getting the max across multiple entries
        $max: "$values"
      },
      "_id": 0
    }
  }
])
```